# Approving a request ticket through digital signatures in php

Tags: php, digital-signature, ticket-system

I am trying to work out a ticketing system, where users can raise requests. Some requests may warrant the users to fill in some downloadable forms, which can be then attached to each request ticket and submitted. On submission, the request is sent to the Reporting Manager for approval.

I want to know if there is any open-source solution for simulating a signature i.e I want each RM to be able to digitally sign the document if the request is approved. How can I go about doing this ?

Comment: Do you mean a mathematical digital signature, using encryption, or a graphical signature as one would sign with a pen?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think PHP is the best chose for this since what you requre is a client solution not server based. You should Consider , Flash , Silverlight , Java or HTM5 Canvas

Here are some quick reference

http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/

http://www.realsignature.com/demo/default.aspx

http://willowsystems.github.com/jSignature/#/demo/

I hope this helps

Comment: I guess I am going to convert all the forms into web based forms.. that makes life much simpler ... :)

Comment: You may try "supersignature" php version for signature capture.